# Strange axis arrangement and outliers in simpe xy-data-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to plot some data (temperatures over hours of the year) from an input file. 
Pretty straight forward: reading in line by line, split by whitespaces to access my row of interest and feed it into lists, then plot:

> pyplot.plot(TRY1.indexList, TRY1.tempList, lw=0.6) 
>   pyplot.xticks(np.arange(0,10000,step=1000))
>   pyplot.yticks(np.arange(-20,40,step=10))

(TRY's are Test Reference Years used in meteorology as some kind of model weather)

The result seems really weird to me. See for yourself:
[image]

So why is my x-axis so badly formatted?
And where do the outliers on the right side of the plot come from? (trust me, they are not in the data)
Anyone ever had similar issues?

Comment: Most probably you forgot to convert your strings to actual numbers before plotting.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are right... Thank you!